# 'No Active Seat' message in Stack Overflow Talent

Tags: support, status-completed, product-support

I'm an administrator on my company's Stack Overflow Talent account. I was able to log in last week and had access to edit our company page. When I logged in this week I was getting the following screen (note: I've changed the company name to be generic):

[image]

Does this mean we need to upgrade our account to allow for more administrators? How can we resolve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It most likely means that your Talent subscription has expired and therefore your seat became inactive. Without an active seat, it's not possible to access Stack Overflow Talent.

Please contact us at talent@stackoverflow.com and we'll be happy to look into your specific account.